# Rails migration on ECS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, amazon-ecs

I am trying to figure out how to run `rake db:migrate` on my ECS service but only on one machine after deployment.

Anyone has experience with that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to run it under a container?

Comment: I dont care how. I just want to automate it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may do it via Amazon ECS one-off task.

1. Build a docker image with rake db migrate as "CMD" in your docker file.
2. Create a task definition. You may choose one task per host while creating the task-definition and desired task number as "1".
3. Run a one-off ECS task inside your cluster. Make sure to make it outside service. Once It completed the task then the container will stop automatically.

You can write a script to do this before your deployment. After that, you can define your other tasks as usual.

You can also refer to the container lifecycle in Amazon ECS here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_life_cycle.html. However, this is the default behavior of the docker.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hey guys, any feedback on this?

Comment: Note that you can reuse your main Rails Docker image and override the command to be run in the Task Definition.

Answer (score 0):

I built a custom shell script to run when my docker containers start ( CMD command in docker ):

```html
#!/bin/sh

web_env=${WEB_ENV:-1}
rails_env=${RAILS_ENV:-staging}
rails_host=${HOST:-'https://www.example.com'}

echo "*****************RAILS_ENV is $RAILS_ENV default to $rails_env"
echo "***************** WEB_ENV is $WEB_ENV default to $web_env"

######## Rails migration ################################################
echo "Start rails migration"
echo "cd /home/app/example && bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=$rails_env"

cd /home/app/example
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=$rails_env
echo "Complete migration"


if [ "$web_env" = "1" ]; then

  ######## Generate webapp.conf##########################################
  web_app=/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/webapp.conf

  replace_rails_env="s~{{rails_env}}~${rails_env}~g"
  replace_rails_host="s~{{rails_host}}~${rails_host}~g"

  # sed: -i may not be used with stdin in MacOsX
  # Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.
  # If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.
  # we use -i.back as backup file for linux and
  # In Macosx require the backup to be specified.
  sed -i.back  -e $replace_rails_env -e $replace_rails_host $web_app
  rm "${web_app}.back" # remove webapp.conf.back cause nginx to fail.
  # sed -i.back  $replace_rails_host $web_app
  # sed -i.back  $replace_rails_server_name $web_app

  ######## Enable Web app ################################################
  echo "Web app: enable nginx + passenger: rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down"
  rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down

else
  ######## Create Daemon for background process ##########################
  echo "Sidekiq service enable: /etc/service/sidekiq/run "
  mkdir /etc/service/sidekiq
  touch /etc/service/sidekiq/run
  chmod +x /etc/service/sidekiq/run

  echo "#!/bin/sh" > /etc/service/sidekiq/run
  echo "cd /home/app/example && bundle exec sidekiq -e ${rails_env}" >> /etc/service/sidekiq/run
fi

echo ######## Custom Service setup properly"
```

What I did was to build a docker image to be run as a web server ( Nginx + passenger) or Sidekiq background process. The script will decide whether it is a web or Sidekiq via ENV variable WEB_ENV and rails migration will always get executed.

This way I can be sure the migration always up to date. I think this will work perfectly for a single task.

I am using a [Passenger docker](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker) that has been designed very easy to customize but if you use another rails app server you can learn from the docker design of Passenger to apply to your own docker design.

Answer (score -1):

For example, you can try something like:

In your **Dockerfile**:

```
CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

Then you create a **start.sh** where you put the commands which you want to execute:

**start.sh**

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

echo "Migrating the database..."
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Rails prevents running migrations in parallel from different processes. Deploying two or more containers in parallel might cause all but one of these deployments to fail. How to handle the mutex?